# Double click with python and tkinter

Tags: python, tkinter

I am learning Python and I need to make it so that once the data is loaded, double click and the `NoCotizacion` and `NumeroPoliza` fields are loaded to the data

```
entry: EntryPolicyNumber = tk.Entry(frame_calendarios)
EntryPolicyNumber.grid(row=3, column=1, padx=10, pady=5) and EntryNroCotizacion = tk.Entry(frame_calendarios)
EntryNroCotizacion.grid(row=3, column=3, padx=0, pady=0)
```

To modify them. but I don't know how to create the double click function for my code.

```
import tkinter as tk
from tkinter import ttk
from tkcalendar import DateEntry
from tree_data import cargaDatos, obtener_fechas

def crearVentana():
    global tree  # Utilizar la variable global tree
    ventana = tk.Tk()  # Cambio aquí, crea una nueva ventana principal
    ventana.title("Ventana PreFactura")
    ventana.geometry("1200x700")  # Establecer el tamaño de la ventana
    
    # Obtener las dimensiones de la pantalla
    screen_width = ventana.winfo_screenwidth()
    screen_height = ventana.winfo_screenheight()

    # Calcular la posición de la ventana para que esté centrada
    window_width = 1200
    window_height = 600
    x = (screen_width - window_width) // 2
    y = (screen_height - window_height) // 2
    ventana.geometry(f"{window_width}x{window_height}+{x}+{y}")

    frame_calendarios = tk.Frame(ventana)
    frame_calendarios.pack(pady=10)

     # Título centrado
    titulo_label = tk.Label(frame_calendarios, text="Este es un título centrado", font=("Helvetica", 16))
    titulo_label.grid(row=0, column=1, columnspan=5, pady=10)

    label_inicio = tk.Label(frame_calendarios, text="Fecha Inicio")
    label_inicio.grid(row=1, column=1, padx=10, pady=5)
    cal_inicio = DateEntry(frame_calendarios, date_pattern='dd/mm/yyyy')
    cal_inicio.grid(row=1, column=2, padx=(0,150), pady=5)

    label_fin = tk.Label(frame_calendarios, text="Fecha Termino")
    label_fin.grid(row=1, column=4, padx=(50,0), pady=5)
    cal_fin = DateEntry(frame_calendarios, date_pattern='dd/mm/yyyy')
    cal_fin.grid(row=1, column=5, padx=(0,100), pady=5)

    btn_aceptar = tk.Button(frame_calendarios, text="Buscar Prefactura", command=lambda: obtener_fechas(cal_inicio, cal_fin, tree))
    btn_aceptar.grid(row=2, column=1, columnspan=5, pady=10)

    tree = ttk.Treeview(ventana, columns=("FechaEmision", "FechaTarificacion", "FechaSolicitud", "InicioVigencia", "NroCotizacion","NumeroPoliza", "NumeroCertificado"),
                        show="headings")
    
    tree.heading("FechaEmision", text="FechaEmision")
    tree.heading("FechaTarificacion", text="FechaTarificacion")
    tree.heading("FechaSolicitud", text="FechaSolicitud")
    tree.heading("InicioVigencia", text="InicioVigencia")
    tree.heading("NroCotizacion", text="NroCotizacion")
    tree.heading("NumeroPoliza", text="NumeroPoliza")
    tree.heading("NumeroCertificado", text="NumeroCertificado")
    tree.pack(fill="both", expand=True)
    
    lblNumeroPoliza = tk.Label(frame_calendarios, text="Numero Poliza")
    lblNumeroPoliza.grid(row=3, column=0, padx=10, pady=5)

    EntryNumeroPoliza = tk.Entry(frame_calendarios)
    EntryNumeroPoliza.grid(row=3, column=1, padx=10, pady=5)

    lblNroCotizacion = tk.Label(frame_calendarios, text="Numero Cotizacion")
    lblNroCotizacion.grid(row=3, column=2, padx=0, pady=0)

    EntryNroCotizacion = tk.Entry(frame_calendarios)
    EntryNroCotizacion.grid(row=3, column=3, padx=0, pady=0)

    scrollbar_y = ttk.Scrollbar(ventana, orient="vertical", command=tree.yview)
    scrollbar_x = ttk.Scrollbar(ventana, orient="horizontal", command=tree.xview)
    tree.configure(yscrollcommand=scrollbar_y.set, xscrollcommand=scrollbar_x.set)
    
    # Ajustar el Treeview al contenido de la ventana
    tree.pack(fill="both", expand=True)
    scrollbar_y.pack(side="right", fill="y")
    scrollbar_x.pack(side="bottom", fill="x")

    ventana.mainloop()
```

Comment: the double click https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27262580/tkinter-binding-mouse-double-click

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Tkinter binding mouse double click](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27262580/tkinter-binding-mouse-double-click)